# codeigniter template parsing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, template-engine

How template parsing in codeigniter actually works ?

I have the following part in a  view file

```
<h2>{blog_heading}</h2>
<div>{blog_entries}</div>
```

and in controller

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data = array(
            'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Title',
            'blog_entries' => $products_array()
            );

$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

it works well , but the problem is that i have many tags like this, so do i need to define everything on controller ?

the problem is with performance , user's wont use all the tags every time.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to split your views into multiple views?  That way, you could only parse the views you actually need.  It sounds as if you have some sort of master view.

Comment: @MaximeMorin For some reasons , i cannot change the structure of views ,also the idea is to make a framework like project ,that means there may be changes in views , but the controller and others will be private(for editing) to users.

Comment: Are you trying to provide a list of available tags to your framework's users that they can use on any views?

Comment: Users means `Developer`  and not in `any views` ,Ex.There is a view called `show_product` and developer can use any product related activities on that view.ex `<div>%products?id=5description=false%</div>` it simply means that show the product with `id=5` but do not show its `description`,its looks like i need to extend the Parsing class.

Comment: I agree with you, you definitively need your own parsing class.  You can extend the core one, but your changes are fairly different, I would build my own.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score -1):

Answering you question, Yes, you should create ALL the variables on your controller. When a user access your controller, you can check in there for "needed" tags, and then display only the needed tags, based on user preferences or your app's requirements. On the views you should only display the tags. If you're doing calculations and changing values on the views that's breaking the entire MVC concept, the entire reason of CodeIgniter.

You shouldn't be creating variables in the controller just because you can :) They need to be created only when needed by your visitors. If you're creating all the tags but not displaying all of them on the views, perhaps you need a way to identify just the needed tags and then create new ones based on user selections and needs, using another controller or the same, with received information.

If you're doing calculations on your controller and then more calculations on the views, that code is not correct for the MVC model. Calculations and definitions have to be done in the controllers. In the views, you can choose if you want to display that variable, based on the condition you need, but never change their content.

In conclusion, all the variables have to be created in the controllers in order to maintain the MVC concept.

Hope this helps you to understand a little more about CodeIgniter. It's an awesome framework, you just need to be sure that you're using it in the right way.

Kind regards.

Comment: Actually what are you trying to say ? coded on my question is just an example only.
To Reply to your Question : tags are not dynamically generated ,its on the file system ,can u suggest me to check the existence of tags in an effective way ?